# Do AE and meta.AE servers work in UTC/GMT time zone?

Tags: support, user-interface

Some days I've noticed how my activity and statistics in Android Enthusiasts site suddenly start being registered as if they belong to next day. My time zone is `Standard Time -05:00 UTC` and, as [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27201/159670) clarifies it for StackOverflow site, I just assumed AE server also work with `00:00 UTC` time, but I'd like to know officially if it is still true for AE servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the GMT time zone and things seem synced up, so I would say it's on the GMT/UTC time.

Also, at the bottom of your data box (when you hover over your username on the top bar), it gives the UTC time.

However, I think winterba.sh is a number of hours ahead...